# Xamarin.ios httpclient 403 forbidden error webservice asmx

Tags: c#, xamarin, https, ssl-certificate, httpclient

I have an GeoTrust Certificate installed on my Server.
In my App i call the webservice with httpclient over https.
When I want to get the data back, the Server give me the following error:
403: Forbidden

Heres the Code:

```
client = new HttpClient(DependencyService.Get<IWebservice>().ApplyCertificateHttpClient());
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://***");
                    var contentAT = new StringContent(mobileJSON, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    var responseAT = await client.PostAsync("***", contentAT);
                    var resultAT = await responseAT.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

In ApplyCertificateHttpClient i do the following:

```
 public NativeMessageHandler ApplyCertificateHttpClient()
    {            
        NativeMessageHandler clientHandler = new NativeMessageHandler() { ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic };

            return clientHandler;

    }
```

How can I Trust my GeoTrust Certificate ?

Comment: 403 sounds like an authentiction issue, not a cert problem

Comment: What is my work around for authentication with the webservice?

Comment: I have no idea, you need to figure out WHY it's returning a 403 first.  Check the server logs

Comment: But why I cant add an ClientCertificate ?
I get always the error, that the method ClientCertificate is not implemented?